Error in android studio when creating Maps program
I am creating a GoogleMaps activity in Android Studio.
I have generated the default Activity from the android studio and it has generated the following code
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private ActivityMapsBinding binding;



 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

When i am trying to run the program it is giving the error
import android.widget.F;
                     ^
  symbol:   class F
  location: package android.widget

in ActivityMainBinding. I have made the following changes too but still the error persists.
In build.gradle i have added
 buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }

In the layout file i have added the layout tag
<layout>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_maps" />
</layout>

If instead of FragmentContainerView i add the fragment tag then it is unable to find the ActivityMapsBinding class.
Can anyone update how to correct this.
